# Failed to deploy web package to IIS website. By the Self-hosted Windows agent

Tags: azure-devops

Failed to deploy web package to IIS website

I have created one ASP.NET Core application and Azure DevOps continuous integration (CI) and continuous delivery (CD) pipeline.

I have created and configure the Self-hosted Windows agents in my local machine as a service. It is working as expected.

When I run the CI/CD pipeline for the first time it is working successfully, and the web application published to my local IIS successfully.

The issue is when I commit another update to Azure DevOps git repository it is failed to deploy web package to my local IIS website with the following errors and warnings

```
2019-08-21T10:56:59.1480862Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to IIS website.
2019-08-21T10:56:59.1492670Z ##[warning]Can\'t find loc string for key: Trytodeploywebappagainwithrenamefileoptionselected
2019-08-21T10:56:59.1493093Z ##[warning]Trytodeploywebappagainwithrenamefileoptionselected
2019-08-21T10:56:59.1493421Z ##[error]Error Code: ERROR_FILE_IN_USE
More Information: Web Deploy cannot modify the file 'DemoWebApp.dll' on the destination because it is locked by an external process.  In order to allow the publish operation to succeed, you may need to either restart your application to release the lock, or use the AppOffline rule handler for .Net applications on your next publish attempt.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FILE_IN_USE.
Error count: 1.
```

I have configured the appOffline rule in the publishing profile (.pubxml) and add the EnableMSDeployAppOffline element to the PropertyGroup like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnableMSDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
</PropertyGroup>
```

As described in More Information’s learn more URL http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FILE_IN_USE.

Still it is failed to deploy web package to my local IIS website with the same errors and warnings.

When I trying to redeploy manually few times then it is working successfully other wise failed with same errors and warnings. Because I think the file is locked for some time in my local machine process.

It is also working successfully when I manually delete all the files from IIS release folder with that locked file.

Needs help, the file is locked by any one local process. I couldn’t find that local process. I couldn’t figure out the issue. I also don’t know if I found that process any how then how to figure out the issue. Is this just local issue?

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was deploying my web app on local iis using `IIS Web App Deploy` task.I was able to reproduce the same error. I found this error occurred if i was visiting my website when i was trying to deploy a new version. And the deploy task failed to update the .dll file, since it was in use.

**I fixed this error by checking this option “Take App Offline”, See below pic.**

Please let me know If you are using different tasks to deploy your web app. 
[image]

Comment: even though I have checked this option, I am unable to deploy my app, as a workaround, I am using IIS utility task to stop and start the website, Can you guide me what's the issue here. am I missing something?

Comment: for me setting [TakeAppOfflineFlag: true] did not worked too

Answer (score 4):

Recycle the application pool immediately before your 'Deploy IIS App' task.
Add a 'WinRM - IIS Web App Management' task to you release pipeline.  Set the Configuration type to 'IIS Application Pool', set the 'Action' to Recycle, and type in the app pool name in the 'Application pool name' field.

The recycle should unlock the dll and allow it to be deleted and replaced in the deployment step.

Comment: This worked for me, however I used IIS web app manage. My guess is that WinRM is for when WinRM is used for remote management instead of the devops agent?

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is between those two tasks.  They appear to have significant overlap in their functions.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same error despite having the `Take App Offline` option set for ages. That can't be the solution. There's some phantom bug going on here, but I did get it resolved without rebooting the server.

- In PROCMON, I [searched Associated Handles](https://www.dariawan.com/tutorials/windows/how-know-which-process-using-file-or-folder-windows/) for the file in use. There were none.
- I tried deleting the app's DLL file outright; an error message said it was in use by `w3wp.exe` even though the website was offline and the app pool stopped.
- I confirmed this by opening IIS and looking at [the worker processes panel](https://support.secureauth.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028718811-Finding-the-Worker-Process-and-PID-of-an-Application-Pool-in-IIS). None of the active `w3wp.exe` PIDs were related to the application I was trying to update.
- I opened PROCMON and sorted by Image name to find any W3WP.exe instances still running. There was one Suspended instance that it wouldn't let me terminate (despite running PROCMON as an admin/with elevation). It simply said "Access is denied."
- I restarted the Agent on the server via the Services window.

At that point, I was able to delete the application DLL from the target directory and deploy normally from DevOps pipelines.

Hopefully this doesn't happen in production.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error .
I splved by checking  the "enable IIS" to my task , like this :
[image]

Now my lob suuccseded